# How to perform CRUD Operations on sharepoint lists using React and PnP-JS Core with SharePoint FrameWork (SharePoint 2016)

Tags: sharepoint-framework, pnp-js-core, react, crud, office-ui-fabric-react

I would like to create forms using react and PnP-JS Core with sharepointframework to perform CRUD Operations on sharepoint lists.

Do you have any simple examples I can look at and test on SharePoint 2016 to help me to get familiarized with this new concept

Thanks,

Arioule

Answer (score 3):

We have taken multiple initiatives where in we are developing client side web-parts using react for our clients. Traditionally we had been using jquery for making ajax requests in script editors.

But with Typescript we are able to use ES6(which is compiled to ES5 at runtime). Using PnP-JS Core with Typescript, we have not only saved a lot of time( by avoiding addition of headers), but our code is more:

1. Indented
2. Readable
3. Debug-gable ( synchronous like debugging by using ES6 promises)
4. Scalable
5. Supports batching ( executing multiple requests in a set order)
6. Supports caching ( loading the content from browser storage, thus less loading time for client)

I have given you few reasons, you might find a lot more on your way.

Comment: Hi Tahir, Thanks a lot for your help. Do you have any simple exemple of SharePoint Framework Webpart using React and PNP-JS-Core that I can deploy and test on SharePoint 2016 to get me familiarized with this new concept.